# Find the top 30% of the industry's revenue in the past 12 months through SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called revenue,
column has revenue and month and industry category and industry surname

How to find out that the revenue in the past 12 months is in the top 30% of the industry,
I need the top 30% in the same industry category.

```
industry surname   revenue     month           industry category   

A                 $2000       2020/01           Agriculture
B                $4000        2020/09           Industrial
C                $9900        2020/05           Agriculture
D                $6000        2020/09           Industrial
A                 $2000       2020/02           Agriculture
B                $3500        2020/08           Industrial
A                 $1000       2020/05           Agriculture
A                 $7000       2020/08           Agriculture
A                 $5000       2020/12           Agriculture
```

industry may A~Z,month may 2020/01~2020/12

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Perhaps a db/SQL fiddle would help.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially "Introduce the problem before you post any code" .  You (currently) do not show what you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Please read [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It has all the find details on how to show info in a table form. And, please, add titles to your list.

Comment: Als you should create  [mre], which includes desired output.

Comment: Presumably further advice will simply go unheeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query will definitely help you

```
SELECT A.*, P.30_PERCENT_REVENUE FROM STACK_USER.revenue AS A
JOIN
(SELECT TRIM(B.industry_category) AS industry_category, (((SELECT SUM(REVENUE) FROM STACK_USER.revenue WHERE industry_category=B.industry_category)/100) *30) 
AS 30_PERCENT_REVENUE FROM STACK_USER.revenue AS B GROUP BY B.industry_category AND MONTH(DATE)>=MONTH(SYSDATE()) AND YEAR(DATE)>=YEAR(SYSDATE())-1) AS P
ON TRIM(A.industry_category)=P.industry_category AND A.revenue>=P.30_PERCENT_REVENUE;
```

I was very confused by your question because the question is not that much clear

so here what I understood is, you have to calculate all category revenue (30%) past 12 month

and the (industry_surname) whose revenue is greater than the past 12 months 30% category revenue so this will give only that result but

here I used the date as a full date below is the script of creating the table

```
CREATE TABLE STACK_USER.REVENUE
(
        INDUSTRY_SURNAME VARCHAR(100), 
        REVENUE FLOAT, DATE DATE, 
        INDUSTRY_CATEGORY VARCHAR(100)
);
```

And inserted this record and performed operation below is the insert script

```
INSERT INTO REVENUE (INDUSTRY_SURNAME, REVENUE, DATE, INDUSTRY_CATEGORY) VALUES 
('A' ,2000,'2020/01/01' ,'Agriculture'),
('B' ,4000,'2020/09/01','Industrial'),
('C',9900,'2020/05/01','Agriculture'),
('D',6000,'2020/09/01','Industrial'),
('A' ,2000,'2020/02/01','Agriculture'),
('B' ,3500,'2020/08/01','Industrial'),
('A' ,1000,'2020/05/01','Agriculture'),
('A' ,7000,'2020/08/01' ,'Agriculture'),
('A' ,5000,'2020/12/01','Agriculture');
```

I Hope you will like my hard work and literally happy to answer your question

if i fulfilled you requirement then please follow me and upvote my answer i would be very happy

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it in detail, thank you for your answer, it is very helpful to me!

Comment: it's exactly the same as what you were expecting

Comment: but If what I am looking for is the top 30% of each industry’s revenue
For example, if there are 100 agricultural companies, and the top 30 companies with more revenue are required, how should the query be changed?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear to me can you please elaborate